# how to addClass('overflow');

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want click a button then it add the class

```
.overflow{overflow-y:scroll};
```

I used `addClass('overflow'}`, but it reload the whole page on clicked.

After an action it will `removeClass('overflow')`
I will not choose to use `.css('overflow','hidden')` because `'auto','scroll','hidden'` is not suitable for me, I want it being completely remove after used.

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Maybe in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It's not clear why your button would reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just use an `<a>` with `href="#"` ?

That wouldn't reload the page and still trigger your script.

In yor posted code u have a minor typo: You ended the `addClass()` with `}` ... This would be the correct code:

`$("#targetElement").addClass('overflow');`

Comment: It's better to use `href="javascript:void(0);"`, otherwise a click would scroll back to the top

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the page to be reloaded:

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();  // this will prevent the link to be followed
   //the rest of your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent page reloading, you should [prevent default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) anchor `click` event:

```
$("a.button").on("click", function(e) {
    // ... addClass("overflow");

    e.preventDefault();  // or instead you may use
                         // return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yourbuttonid").click(function(e){

    //your code

    e.preventDefault();  // this will prevent the link's default action
                         // make sure it comes last in your code,
                         // if not it will cancel your code from executing.

});
```